# Torchvision Faster-RCNN, modified loss function

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, data-science-model, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to solve a problem of table detection in spreadsheets in Excels. I've came across this [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/01/TableSense_AAAI19.pdf), which suggests to use modified version of Faster RCNN to do object detection on the spreadsheets.

The idea is a follow: Vectorize each sheet, extracting features(such as `has_value`, `length`, `bg_color`, `date_format` ETC...), having a total of 20 features for each cell. Then feed the input into a `Faster RCNN`, but with this tweeks:

- Change the backbone, enabling it to handle multiple channels as opposed to RGB of a regular image, and also remove the pooling layers.
- Use a different evaluation metric, EoB and EoB2, where EoB stands for exact match, and EoB2 stands for a match with up to 2 deviations in any direction from the target
- Use a custom loss function for the bounding box regression, as follows:
  Combine the original loss of the Bounding box regression with this:

$$
LPBR(t, t^1) = \sum_{i \in \{top, bottom, left, right\}} R(t_i - t^1_i) 
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
R(x) = \begin{cases}
0.5x^2, & \text{if } |x| < k, 
0.5k^2, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation} $$

Were R is used instead of `smoothL1`, for precise regression (which is needed here as opposed to regular object detection objectives).

Now to the problem, I'm not sure where I need to implement this loss function in the Faster RCNN module, the losses it produces are: loss_classifier,  loss_box_reg, loss_objectness and loss_rpn_box_reg. `loss_box_reg` and `loss_rpn_box_reg` sounds suitable, but I'm not sure which one(or both). I found them under [torchvision.models.detection.roi_heads.fastrcnn_loss](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/roi_heads.py) and [torchvision.models.detection.rpn.RegionProposalNetwork.compute_loss](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/rpn.py) , but thier inputs are tensors with many predicitions and many target boxes, although I only have about 2-3 actual tables in my targets, so I'm not sure if I'm interpreting what I need to do right. For now I've changed `fastrcnn_loss` using this code:

```
def custom_regression_loss(class_logits, box_regression, labels, regression_targets):
    """
    Computes the loss for Faster R-CNN.

    Args:
        class_logits (Tensor)
        box_regression (Tensor)
        labels (list[BoxList])
        regression_targets (Tensor)

    Returns:
        classification_loss (Tensor)
        box_loss (Tensor)
    """

    labels = torch.cat(labels, dim=0)
    regression_targets = torch.cat(regression_targets, dim=0)

    classification_loss = F.cross_entropy(class_logits, labels)

    # get indices that correspond to the regression targets for
    # the corresponding ground truth labels, to be used with
    # advanced indexing
    sampled_pos_inds_subset = torch.where(labels > 0)[0]
    labels_pos = labels[sampled_pos_inds_subset]
    N, num_classes = class_logits.shape
    box_regression = box_regression.reshape(N, box_regression.size(-1) // 4, 4)

    box_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(
        box_regression[sampled_pos_inds_subset, labels_pos],
        regression_targets[sampled_pos_inds_subset],
        beta=1 / 9,
        reduction="sum",
    )

    #################### THIS IS MY ADDITION ###############
    pbr_loss = calculate_pbr_loss(
        box_regression[sampled_pos_inds_subset, labels_pos], regression_targets[sampled_pos_inds_subset]
    ) / (labels_pos.numel())
    # print(box_regression[sampled_pos_inds_subset, labels_pos])
    # print(regression_targets[sampled_pos_inds_subset])
    box_loss = box_loss / labels.numel()

    total_box_loss = box_loss + pbr_loss

    return classification_loss, total_box_loss
```

But my model doesn't converge as stated in the paper, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone point me to the right direction?